# How to convert character into Date in R?

Tags: r, sparkr

I have an excel file where dates are in below format.
01-Jan-2020
03-Jun-2015

I need to convert this in Date. I have tried with many converting techniques.I am getting NA every time.

Comment: have you tried `as.Date(variable)`?

Comment: Also, please include your data and what you have tried so we don't waste your time suggesting things you have alredy done

Comment: yes i have tried as.Date and lubridate:: mdy but i am not getting the result

Comment: You need to put that in you question along with a sample of your data and the output you get

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
x <- c("01-Jan-2020", "03-Jun-2015")

as.Date(x, format = "%d-%b-%Y")
#> [1] "2020-01-01" "2015-06-03"

# Or with lubridate
lubridate::dmy(x)
#> [1] "2020-01-01" "2015-06-03"
```

We can confirm `x` was converted from character to date with:

```
y <- list(input = x,
          lubridate = lubridate::dmy(x),
          base = as.Date(x, format = "%d-%b-%Y"))

str(y)

#> List of 3
#> $ input    : chr [1:2] "01-Jan-2020" "03-Jun-2015"
#> $ lubridate: Date[1:2], format: "2020-01-01" "2015-06-03"
#> $ base     : Date[1:2], format: "2020-01-01" "2015-06-03"
```

Comment: > y <- list(input = abc2$`Maturity date`,
+           lubridate = lubridate::dmy(abc2$`Maturity date`),
+           base = as.Date(abc2$`Maturity date`, format = "%d-%b-%Y"))
> str(y)
List of 3
 $ input    : POSIXct[1:12274], format: NA NA NA NA ...
 $ lubridate: Date[1:12274], format: NA NA NA NA ...
 $ base     : Date[1:12274], format: NA NA NA NA ...

Comment: Sample Data :-01-FEB-2046
01-MAR-2019
30-APR-2021
30-APR-2021
09-MAY-2022
09-MAY-2022
09-MAY-2022
01-MAR-2038
01-SEP-2022
01-AUG-2032
01-AUG-2044
25-OCT-2017

Answer (score 0):

Download and install "Lubridate" library.

```
wget https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/archive/v1.6.0.tar.gz
sudo R CMD INSTALL v1.6.0.tar.gz
```

It contains a method called, "parse_date_time2()"
You can parse the date in any format.
Ex.

```
parse_date_time2("21 Jan 2010", orders = "dmy")
```

Check for reference.
https://www.displayr.com/r-date-conversion/

Comment: lubridate::parse_date_time2("21-Jan-2017",orders = "dmy")  :::: output - NA

Comment: I have solved it by replacing '-' with '/' in the data.It worked for me